# Is there an Idiom for someone who tried but failed because it was too much for him

Tags: idioms, translation

I'm wondering if there's an idiom similar to an idiom in Czech.
In Czech, it's 'Vylámat si na něčem zuby' ~ 'To break one's teeth on something'.

To try and do something but failing nonetheless.
It's almost always used after the fact, but it can be used as a warning too.

'He tried to untighten the screw and spent all day on it and still nothing. He broke his teeth on it.'

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for **bite off more than you can chew**?

> To try to do something that is too difficult for you:

*We bit off more than we could chew in our original reform proposals.*

[Cambridge Dictionary]